# Vue fetch issue

Tags: json, vue.js, fetch, http-status-code-404

I want to update some data with fetch.
The code looks like this:

```
 methods: {
    updateEmails() {
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/selectedMailAccounts", {
        method: "PATCH",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(["info@email.com", "email@email.com"]),
      });
    },
  },
```

When the function gets called I get this error in my console:

> PATCH http://localhost:3000/selectedMailAccounts 404 (Not Found)

As I open the URL in the browser I can see the data, so it exists:

```
[
  "company@email.com",
  "info@gmail.com",
]
```

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

> As I open the URL in the browser I can see the data, so it exists

No, when you open it in your browser it uses `GET` method (not `PATCH` like your `fetch`). Hence those are two different webservices.

Your problem is not the `fetch` method. Check your back-end code if your `PATCH` webservice has been correctly configured.